# Fluid: f:uri with Javascript variable

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I try to use a Javascript Variable in f:uri but it is not parsed correctly. Can you help to build the String?

```
fachid = $("#auswahlisteFaecher" ).val();
alert(fachid);
var URL = "<f:uri.action action='show' arguments='{test: '"+fachid+"'}' />";
window.location.href=  URL;
```

I also tried it with CDATA

```
"<f:uri.action action='show' arguments='{test: <![CDATA[fachid}]]>' />";
```

HTML Output:

```
var URL = "<f:uri.action action='show' arguments='{test: '"+fachid+"'}' />";
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. The Fluid ViewHelpers are parsed when TYPO3 renders the page, and this is of course before JavaScript comes into play.

You can do as follows:

```
<script>
# Generate a "neutral" link to the showAction
var showActionUri = '<f:uri.action action="show" noCacheHash="true" />';

$('body').on('change', '#auswahllisteFaecher', function() {
   var fachUid =  $("#auswahlisteFaecher" ).val();
   # Attach the fach that should be selected for the single view
   var showFachUri = showActionUri + '?tx_myext_myplugin[fach]=' + fachUid;
   window.location.href = showFachUri   
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I get this error and don't understand it.
Page Not Found
Reason: Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash comparison failed)